# Consulta editable en Excel

Tags: excel, tablas

actualmente tengo una consulta, donde la ejecuto en un excel. Al actulizar me proporciona una tabla con una serie de datos, hasta ahi bien.

Me gustaria trabajar con esa tabla, es decir, desde excel, añadirle columnas para poder registrar datos a mano. Mi "problema" viene cuando actualizo, las filas cambian de orden, ya sea por que se han borrado registros u otro motivo.

Un ejemplo para que se entieda mejor seria:

| ejercicio_CONSULTA____ | orden fabricación_CONSULTA__ | comentario manual_EXCEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023____________________ | 200002__________________________ | comentario xxx |
| 2023____________________ | 200003__________________________ | _______________ |

-El problema que tengo es que cada vez que actualizo la consulta, el "comentario xxx" cambia de fila .

Dicho comportamiento es normal que lo haga, pues no hay ninguna relación. Por lo tanto, mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿Hay alguna manera/idea para que siempre mantengan el orden? Ya sea en la programacion de la consulta o alguna funcion en el excel.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: En todo momento mencionaste "una consulta", pero no _qué consulta_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. No está demás recordar además que el sitio es acerca de preguntas sobre _programación_. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Los datos se muestran tal cual estén configurados en la propia consulta. Mira cómo es y configúrala según tus necesidades